# Специфические для проекта настройки плагинов в sublime text 3

Tags: sublime-text

Собственно, есть плагин "PHP Codebeautifier". В конфиге у него (phpcbf.sublime-settings) :

```
{
  "path": "/usr/bin/phpcbf",
  "level": "psr2",
  "patch": "true",
  "encoding": "UTF-8",
  "on_save": true,
  "on_load": false,
  "syntaxes": [
      "Packages/PHP/PHP.tmLanguage",
      "Packages/PHP/PHP.sublime-syntax"
  ],
  "suffix": "",
  "sniffs": [],
  "tab_width": "2"
}
```

Тем не менее - хотелось бы для отдельных проектов задать `{"level": "Drupal"}`.

Существует ли какой-либо стандартный метод или, в противном случае, дополнительный плагин (как я понял - под ST2 подходил https://bitbucket.org/klorenz/projectspecific) для этого?